# Magento 1.9 : Getting customer information on magento success page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How can i get the both guest and registered customer details such as Firstname and Telephone number on success page ?

I am having order# on that page, So can i get the customer information from order# there ?

Comment: Do you want the info associated with the order like the billing/shipping info or something else?

Comment: I need the customer fisrtname and mobile number from the order placed on success.phtml , So i can send him the transactional message to customer for his/her order confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a blog post regarding it. You will get all the information required from there.

Check the link: [Thank you page Magento](http://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/custom-thank-you-page-in-magento-success-phtml/)

Link2: [Thank you page part II](http://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/custom-thank-you-page-in-magento-success-phtml-part-2/)

Let me know if you have any doubts or queries regarding it.

Basically you will get all the required stuff from

```
$lastOrder = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->load(Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->getLastOrderId());
```

and

```
$orderObj = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks.. i will check it out and will get back to you.

Comment: You don't want to to a load inside a foreach. At all. Please check your code since it will decrease the performance if used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I haven't noticed it as it was written long time ago when i was just starting to learn Magento. I'll correct it.

Comment: Thanks @Dexter , your guide was really helpful. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by using

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());?>
```

and then retrieve the customer info from the order object like this

```
//If they have no customer id, they're a guest.
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
    echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
} else {
    //else, they're a normal registered user.
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
}
```

Comment: this solution was having some issues, Dexter's solution worked for me. Thanks for your help.